# Which is the Live server extension available for WebStorm?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, plugins, ide, webstorm

In VS Code, we have Live server extension available to publish content live on server.
But same extension is not available for WebStorm IDE.

Is there any alternative plugin available in WebStorm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the [HTML Preview](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2022.3/editing-html-files.html#ws_html_preview_output_procedure) functionality? It works out of the box, no plugins are required.